# Constructing a date with year and month

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to construct a date from just a year and month. I'm currently running a query like this:

```
SELECT
    yyyy_mm_dd AS 
    t.year,
    t.month,
    t.id,
    t.name,
    ...,
    ...
    ...
FROM(
    SELECT
        p.last_yyyy_mm_dd,
        p.id,
        p.name,
    FROM(
        SELECT
            t.*,
            MAX(yyyy_mm_dd) OVER (PARTITION BY last_day(yyyy_mm_dd)) as last_yyyy_mm_dd
        FROM
            table1 t
        WHERE
            yyyy_mm_dd IS NOT NULL
            AND name = 'XXX'
    ) p
    WHERE
        yyyy_mm_dd = last_yyyy_mm_dd
) p
RIGHT JOIN(
    SELECT
        YEAR(yyyy_mm_dd) as year,
        MONTH(yyyy_mm_dd) as month,
        id,
        name,
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
    FROM
        table2
    WHERE
        yyyy_mm_dd IS NOT NULL
        AND name = 'XXX'
    GROUP BY
        1,2,3,4
    ) t
ON
    p.id = t.id
    AND YEAR(p.last_yyyy_mm_dd) = t.year
    AND MONTH(p.last_yyyy_mm_dd) = t.month
```

On the top level select, I'd like to also have a date (YYYY-MM-DD) field constructed from the year and month. The day part should be the last day of the given month. I.e. for January it'll be 31.

I've looked here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions and can see `last_day` which might be useful, however there doesn't seem to be a make date function like in MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html. How can I construct a date like this in Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have normal date, you can extract `yyyy-MM` using `substr` or `date_format`:

```
select substr('2020-01-15',1,7);
OK
2020-01

select date_format('2020-01-15','yyyy-MM');
OK
2020-01
```

To get last month day from normal date, you can use last_day

```
select last_day(concat(substr('2020-01-15',1,7),'-01'));
OK
2020-01-31
```

And if you have yyyy-MM and want last month day, concat it with '-01' and apply last_day:

```
select last_day(concat('2020-01','-01'));
OK
2020-01-31
```

Comment: I'm trying to build the date while using my selected `month` and `year` column. How could I apply the above while using those columns?

Comment: @stackq concatenate them using concat(year, '-',month). And if you want last day then select last_day(concat(year, '-', month,'-01')); If the month is not a two digit string, use lpad(month, 2, 0) to get two digit month before concatenetion

Answer (score 0):

try the next code. It works for me:

```
select to_date(date_sub(add_months(concat(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2020-01','yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM'),'-01'),1),1))
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2020-01-31  |
+-------------+--+
```